# How do I change the python EXE reference path for tensorboard?

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorboard

I trained an RL agent and want to view the tensorboard output.  When I run:

```
tensorboard --logdir=runs
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\ME\.conda\envs\DELETED_ENV\python.exe" 
"C:\Users\ME\.conda\envs\current_env\Scripts\tensorboard.exe" --logdir=runs': 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The issue I can see is that the python.exe it's trying to use is in a deleted environment.  I am not sure how tensorboard is still referencing this or how to change it.  It's not in my PYTHONPATH.  The PYTHONPATH only has the current_env.

I confirmed the runs folder is in the directory with a tensorboard file.  I have used this before, likely before I deleted that env where the python.exe is, and it all worked fine.

How would I change where tensorboard is looking for the python.exe file to be the current environment?

Thank you!

Comment: What's pip output when venv is active?

Comment: if on a windows machine, please try clearing all the relevant dirs in ```C:/Users/YourAccount/AppData/Roaming/``` and ```C:/ProgramData/```; these usually would have names related to tensorboard. also, this might be helpful: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2534

Comment: @TimurU I'm not sure what you mean by pip output?

Comment: @mindoverflow Thank you!  I saw that link in my google search but I couldn't make out what I should be doing with my app from it.  I will take a look at the directories you referenced and see if this helps.

Comment: Modify the environment variables, you may be using residual environment variables.

Comment: @lazy  Thanks! I did double check the env. variables and they are all up to date and not referencing the deleted env.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `C:\Users\ME\.conda\envs\DELETED_ENV\` if it exists.

This seems to be an issue of misplaced executables.
Most likely, the issue will be resolved if you dump your python dir at

```
C:\Users\ME\.conda\envs\current_env\
```

as the **Scripts** directory looks for `python.exe` in its parent directory by default.

- Run your command from the **Scripts** directory itself first and see if it works.
- If it fails, remove the **__pycache__** folder from the **Scripts** directory.
- If things are still failing, try removing *PYTHONPATH* and python, conda related items from **PATH** temporarily. Please make a note of paths before you remove them so you can restore them if needed.

May I suggest [**Anaconda3**](https://www.anaconda.com/download) which usually manages these issues and an uninstall is not leaving behind records willy nilly that make come back to haunt you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i forgot to mention there should also be a file ```Environments.txt``` in your .conda dir. usually that can be changed to use custom paths